# Makefile: Wildcard for two programs with different source files

Tags: makefile

I'm working on a C project with two programs, a server and a client.
My projects structure:

```
.
+--/bin
|  +--/client
|  +--/server
|
+--/lib
|  +--header1.h
|  +--header2.h
|  +--header3.h
|
+--/obj
|  +--/client
|  +--/server
|
+--/src
|  +--/client
|  |  +--files.c
|  +--/server
|     +--otherfiles.c
|
+--Makefile
```

Now I'm stuck on the Makefile, both my programs need different and some overlapping headers. I tried looking into other projects/repositories, but that didn't help me.
This is what i currently got:

```
SOURCES_CLIENT = ${wildcard src/client/files.c}
SOURCES_SERVER = ${wildcard src/client/otherfiles.c}

HEADERS_CLIENT = ${wildcard lib/header1.h lib/header2.h}
HEADERS_SERVER = ${wildcard lib/header2.h lib/header3.h}

OBJ_CLIENT = ${SOURCES_CLIENT:.c=.o}
OBJ_SERVER = ${SOURCES_SERVER:.c=.o}

CC = gcc
CFLAGS = #not relevant

all: client server

client: ${OBJ_CLIENT}
    ${CC} -o $@ $^

server: ${OBJ_SERVER}
    ${CC} -o $@ $^
```

How would I create wildcard rules to convert my source files to object files (in the correct bin/ directory) using the corresponding header files? Also my Makefile seems to be optimizable, if so how?

Comment: just to clarify, you're asking how you can generate rules in your Makefile to say that (for example) foo.c depends on foo.h?

Comment: You appear to be naming the wanted files explicitly, which is fine.  In that case, however, the `wildcard` function (which, btw, is GNU-specific) isn't doing anything for you.

Comment: @ChrisTurner I'm looking for a rule that compiles `/src/client/foo.c` to `/lib/client/foo.o` while depending on the corresponding headers i.e.  `${HEADERS_CLIENT}`.  EDIT: the rule should be dynamic so also for the server.

Comment: I urge you to instead choose either a conventional build, where the object files go into the same directory as their corresponding sources, or a full-fledged out-of-source build (via `VPATH`).  What you're trying to do *can* be done, but it's the messiest alternative, and it provides little, if any, advantage.

Comment: Also, do you really want the `.o` files under `lib/`?  What, then, is the `obj/` directory for?

Comment: @JohnBollinger In my real code they actually make sense, I just simplified my example by naming the files explicitly.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thanks, it's a typo I meant obj/, but I can't change it anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose your base variable definitions must actually look more like this:

```
SOURCES_CLIENT = ${wildcard src/client/*.c}
SOURCES_SERVER = ${wildcard src/server/*.c}

HEADERS_CLIENT = ${wildcard lib/client*.h}
HEADERS_SERVER = ${wildcard lib/server*.h}
```

One of the very first things you need to understand about `make` is that it knows just about *nothing* about build tools, directories, or files.  It just manipulates strings, and chooses a subset of the strings it works with and forms to issue as shell commands, with timing and order governed by the ruleset expressed to it.

Among the implications is that if you want to build a given target then you have to write a rule for *exactly* that target.  In particular, when you run `make` from the root directory of your project, the wanted binaries (in your scheme) are ***not*** `client` and `server`, they are `bin/client` and `bin/server`.  Similarly, the wanted object file corresponding to `src/client/files.c` is not `files.o` or `src/client/files.o` but rather `obj/client/files.o`.

Having understood that, the next order of business is to define the object file lists correctly.  You seem deeply committed to GNU make already, which makes things easier (at some cost in portability).  Instead of your current definitions for `OBJ_CLIENT` and `OBJ_SERVER`, which provide for object files in a different location than you require, something using a (GNU-specific) substitution reference like this would work:

```
OBJ_CLIENT = $(SOURCES_CLIENT:src/client/%.c=obj/client/%.o)
OBJ_SERVER = $(SOURCES_SERVER:src/server/%.c=obj/server/%.o)
```

Having done that, however, you'll need to write explicit rules for building the object files; `make`'s default rules do not handle the needed cross-directory correspondence.  You can use GNU pattern rules effectively for this purpose.  This is also where you would introduce the dependencies on the headers:

```
obj/client/%.o: src/client/%.c $(HEADERS_CLIENT)
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

Again taking into account the fact that you must provide build rules naming the targets you actually want to build, you might put this all together as:

```
SOURCES_CLIENT = $(wildcard src/client/*.c)
SOURCES_SERVER = $(wildcard src/server/*.c)

HEADERS_CLIENT = $(wildcard lib/client*.h)
HEADERS_SERVER = $(wildcard lib/server*.h)

OBJ_CLIENT = $(SOURCES_CLIENT:src/client/%.c=obj/client/%.o)
OBJ_SERVER = $(SOURCES_SERVER:src/server/%.c=obj/server/%.o)

CC = gcc
CFLAGS = #not relevant

all: bin/client bin/server

bin/client: $(OBJ_CLIENT)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^

bin/server: $(OBJ_SERVER)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^

obj/client/%.o: src/client/%.c $(HEADERS_CLIENT)
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

obj/server/%.o: src/server/%.c $(HEADERS_SERVER)
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

Comment: Thanks, for the detailed answer. This really cleared things up about Makefiles.

Answer (score 1):

These two rules should do what you're after

```
obj/client/%.o: src/client/%.c $(HEADERS_CLIENT)  
        $(CC) -c -o $@ $<

obj/server/%.o: src/server/%.c $(HEADERS_SERVER)
        $(CC) -c -o $@ $<
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot.